Render quarto documents in another directory using tar_quarto
I have a R workflow set up using {targets} and {tarchetypes} packages. A a certain point I use tarchetypes::tar_quarto() to render a document, which is placed in the same directory containing the quarto document.
How can I render the quarto document and place it in another directory?
Right now I have this code on my workflow, which will place the rendered document in report folder.
  tar_quarto(
    relatorio_suspeitos,
    'report/relatorio_suspeitos.qmd'
  ),

I'd like to have the .qmd file in one folder and the rendered output created in another folder (output/relatorio_suspeitos.pdf).

The store to store the rendered document is managed by quarto instead of targets. So I think in targets we cannot specify that.
